# TippyJS: Rendering a tippy with "interactive" set makes it (almost) invisble

Tags: popover, tippyjs

I wanted to create a Tippy with a button in it:

```
let tippyActions = function() {
var tippys = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="tippy"]');
tippys.forEach(tpy => tippy(tpy, {content: tippyContent(tpy),
                                  placement: "left",
                                  trigger: 'click',
                                  allowHTML: true,
                                  hideOnClick: false,
                                  interactive: true, 
                                  //zIndex: 99999,}))
}

let tippyContent = function ( tpy) {
    let buttonsDiv = document.createElement("div")
    let btn1 = document.createElement("a")
    btn1.href = `/go/${tpy.url}`
    buttonsDiv.appendChild(btn1);
    return buttonsDiv.innerHTML;
}
```

But as soon as I set the `interactive` flag to `true` the tippys body disappears:

[image]

After reading a bit I first thought I have a `zIndex` problem, but that apparently was not it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that I missed to read a part of the FAQ section in the documentary, where it states that adding `appendTo: document.body` can solve the problem, which it did in my case:

```
let tippyActions = function() {
    var tippys = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="tippy"]');
    tippys.forEach(tpy => tippy(tpy, {content: tippyContent(tpy),
                                      placement: "left",    
                                      trigger: 'click',
                                      allowHTML: true,    
                                      hideOnClick: false,    
                                      appendTo: document.body,   // <---
                                      interactive: true}))
}
```